# Use Local Storage as an autosave proxy - good or bad?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, local, local-storage, autosave

We are developing a web app that uses **auto save** as a save pattern. With that feature came some quite unexpected UI problems.

In order to enhance the user understanding of the concept, we wanted to make the autosave instant, not periodic with visual feedback everytime the document is saved.

We thought about using local storage as a temporary data cache, and then just set a slower interval that synchronizes all user data with the web server in the background. This might have some bad side-effects when dealing with possible revision conflict scenarios.

Has anyone had any experience with autosave patterns and/or using local storage as a data proxy, and can share some valuable information

Answer (score 0):

i assume by instant you mean after every user edit action (or keypress or whatever)?
it depends on what data you have here.
if you have only text documents i see no reason why not to directly interact with the server
but i would add some sleep time like for example:

if the user edits something set a switch to edited  = true,
if the last commit is longer than 10 seconsd ago, commit the current state (the document may have changed in this time, use current state)
set last commit switch to current time.

i think a local buffer is very complicated and probably brings more pain than its useful.

however if you decide to the common way to do it is to fill the buffer at a higher frequency (but using the method described above), and let it transmit to the server at a lower frequency (also using the methods above). a timestamp/incrementid is passed from the first to the second to the third buffer etc.
when restoring the content from all buffers or storage servesr is fetched and the latest version (with the increment id from the first buffer) is used.

Comment: Bu why add a sleep time at all? If we use local storage, the save can be instant. The local buffer frequency could be on each user action and the server frequency on every, say, 10 seconds.

Comment: can it? depends on your data and application. if the save procedure doesnt take more than some ms its probably ok. some literature on this subjecs designs real time interaction has a tolerancy of 50 ms latency in total... incorrect in my point of view. but stated from the teaching books you are okay if the edit action and the save action stay under 50 ms. but imagine photoshop would autosave your project files on every modification ... its not like everything local is instand and you have endless ressources. thats why there are better computers than others and ram and cpu and stuff is a factor

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that the data is only text, and mostly small notes.

Comment: yeah, then you can probably do that.